# IntentService doesn't save my object after building him

Tags: java, android, intentservice, bluetooth-lowenergy

I got a wierd situation that an object I build return to be null in method onHandleIntent and I don't know why or how to solve it.

MyActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // the bluetooth is mentioned in case you know a way to use it with out transfer it from the activity
        BluetoothManager _bluetooth_manager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        myService = new MyService(new MyClass(_bluetooth_manager.getAdapter()));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
}
```

---

MyService

```
private MyClass X;

 public MyService(MyClass x) {
    super("man");    //not so much in the movie... =p
    X = x;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // somehow X is null here after i set him in the constractor. any idea why?
}
```

---

If someone can edit my title i'm not sure i wrote it well and clear to understand... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constructor will never be used. Your `IntentService` has, elsewhere, a zero-argument `MyService` constructor — that will be the constructor that Android uses to create the instance of your service.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So how can I transfer MyClass into the IntentService?

Comment: I'll answer to that myself, i'll use Intent.putExtra() it will probably work.

Comment: @LamaTo: I am not certain that a class can go in an extra. Use a extra as a flag to indicate what the work is, not the class that should do the work. The class is an implementation detail of the `IntentService`.

Comment: You can put an arbitrary object into an extra if you want, but it must either implement the Serializable interface, or be Parcelable (which is more than just an interface)